# Use of Excel formula 'IF" and "AND" with multiple sheet to combine the data

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have two excel datasheets i.e. 'Data' and 'Sheet1'. Now, I am using the following excel formula to bring some data from 'Sheet1' to 'Data':

```
=IF(AND(Data!B2=Sheet1!A2,Data!C2="Argentina"),Data!AU2:CR2=Sheet1!B2:AY2,NAN)
```

The formula return "#NAME?".

Can you help solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to mention destination sheet cells in formula. If function doesn't accept this. Try below formula

```
=IF(AND(Data!B2=Sheet1!A2,Data!C2="Argentina"),Sheet1!B2,"NAN")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Harun24HR. Actually, I need multiple values to return using the 'if' function if the condition is matched. Say, data contained in cells (B2:AY2) in excel sheet-"sheet1" need to be returned in cells (AU2:CR2) in sheet-"Data" if the conditioned is matched (as defined in the question above). I have only two data sheets: "Data" and "Sheet1". The destination sheet is "Data" from "Sheet1" for the mentioned cells.

Comment: Something like this. But not working: ```=IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="Argentina"),AU2:CR2=Sheet1!B2:AY2,False)```

Comment: This will never work `AU2:CR2=Sheet1!B2:AY2`. What is your excel version. Show some sample data. If you have Excel-365 then could try `=IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="Argentina"),Sheet1!B2:AY2,False)`

Comment: Understand. Thanks, @@Harun24HR.

Answer (score 0):

This is advise too large to fit into a comment:

In order to solve such an issue, you can use Formula auditing: it gets into your formula and solves it step by step.

After some evaluations, I get the question to evaluate this formula:

```
=IF(FALSE, Data!AU2:CR2=Sheet1!B2:AY2, NAN)
```

And the moment it wants to evaluate `Data!AU2:CR2=Sheet1!B2:AY2`, I get an error.

I tried to put this formula excerpt as a single formula into a sheet, and as a result I got a complete row, filled with boolean values (which does not fit into one single cell, explaining the problem).

What are you trying to do here? Do you want every single value to be equal? Do you want matches? ...

Comment: Thanks @Dominique.  Cells (B2:AY2) in "sheet1" need to be returned into cells (D2:BA2) in sheet-"Data" if the conditions are matched (as defined). I can do this: ```IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="RED"),Sheet1!B2,FALSE)``` and ```IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="RED"),Sheet1!C2,FALSE)```  continue till ...```IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="RED"),Sheet1!AY2,FALSE)```. Now instead of repeating the same formula every time, I want one formula, like this:  ```=IF(AND(B2=Sheet1!A2,C2="RED"),D2:BA2=Sheet1!B2:AY2,False)``` . The least part of the formula `D2:BA2=Sheet1!B2:AY2, False` has issues. What can be done here?